# Create a detached screen with a screenname and commands

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to launch a detached screen that has a screenname and also has running commands.

I've seen other posts that say to use `screen -dmS ScreenName` to create a named screen, then use `screen -r ScreenName -X stuff $'MyCommands\n'` to give it commands to run.

The problem with this is I want the screen to terminate after my commands are run, but doing the above screen commands separately means `MyCommands` will execute and then after completed the screen will wait and not terminate.

The problem seems to be creating a screen with a screenname AND with commands.

Any ideas on how to get around this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't figure out how to do it on one line, but this solution provides me with the same affect I was looking for.

```
screen -dmS ScreenName
screen -x ScreenName -X stuff $'MyCommands\nexit\n'
```

The first line creates my screen with a specified name, the second line passes `MyCommands` to run in the screen, followed by the `exit` command which ends up terminating the screen after all of my commands have completed.